# Несколько if/else в одной функции

Tags: python, if

Есть код, который нужно проверять на наличие того или иного текста.

```
    def configtest(self):
        if "http://" in self.setgui.url_conf.text():
            pass
        else:
            self.gui.consolelog.appendPlainText("URL must have - http://")
        if self.setgui.url_conf.text == "":
            self.gui.consolelog.appendPlainText("The string - Name, cannot be empty!")
        else:
            pass
        if self.setgui.process_count.text == "":
            self.gui.consolelog.appendPlainText("Count of processes can't be 0.")
        else:
            self.configmain()
```

Нужно если верно, переходить к след. проверке. Возможно ли такое, а если да, то как провернуть?

Comment: возможно. делайте вложенные if

Comment: А можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно не то что вам нужно но все же есть рекомендации по коду
В первой проверке можно сократить код до 2 строчек использую not

```
if "http://" not in self.setgui.url_conf.text():
    self.gui.consolelog.appendPlainText("URL must have - http://")
```

Далее вторая проверка сокращаеться

```
if self.setgui.url_conf.text == "":
    self.gui.consolelog.appendPlainText("The string - Name, cannot be empty!")
```

И в итоге выходит если использовать вложенный if то возможно вариант решения -

```
def configtest(self):
    if "http://" in self.setgui.url_conf.text():
        if self.setgui.url_conf.text != "":
            if self.setgui.process_count.text != "":
                self.configmain()
            else:
                self.gui.consolelog.appendPlainText("Count of processes can't be 0.")
        else:
            self.gui.consolelog.appendPlainText("The string - Name, cannot be empty!")
    else:
        self.gui.consolelog.appendPlainText("URL must have - http://")
```

Comment: Проблема была решена, но ответ очень сильно похож, на то, что у меня вышло. Из-за таких людей, этот форум ещё живет. Спасибо!